# How to pass value from php to simple html without javascript?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to update my HTML a ref tag with with php GET Info, however i can't seem to replace get the value

Here is the HTML

```
$message = '<h2>Your confirmation link</h2>
<p>Click on this <a href="127.0.0.1/ResendVerification.php?passkey=$verification_Code">link</a> to activate your account</p>';
```

I'm trying to replace the $verification_Code with the actual code that i already have, however it's not replacing for some reason, any guidance ?

Comment: use double quotes.single quotes doesn't evaluate variables

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the localhost machine - that IP address is not reachable by another machine as it would refer to itself. The whole string is within single quotes so PHP variables are not parsed as such - you need to escape from the single quotes, like `<a href=/ResendVerification.php?passkey='.$verification_code.'>link</a>` etc

Comment: i changed the ip only in this question , its real correct ip in actual code

Comment: OK, but you need to either escape the single quotes or wrap the entire string with double quotes

Comment: i wrapped the whole thing with a double quotes and still didn't work

Comment: okay it works, but when i get the email , the href isn't working? it's not highlighted blue its just a normal string

Comment: Add some css or inline styles. You say the `href is not working` - be precise about how it is "not working"

Comment: the href shows now as "[ip/ResendVerification.php?passkey=code]" but it should show as only clickable "link" as show in my html in the question

Comment: have you got the `http://` or `https://` before the ip / host?

Comment: that was the issue thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the quotes `"` and `'`.

You mix the type of quotes between HTML and PHP. I would suggest to use single quotes for PHP and double quotes for HTML. Then, the correct string is:

```
<?php
$message = '<h2>Your confirmation link</h2>
    <p>Click on this <a href="127.0.0.1/ResendVerification.php? 
    passkey=' . $verification_Code . '">link</a> to activate your account</p>';
```

When you use double quotes for PHP, then the HTML string requires escaping of the quotes `\"` and the correct string is:

```
<?php
$message = "<h2>Your confirmation link</h2>
    <p>Click on this <a href=\"127.0.0.1/ResendVerification.php? 
    passkey=$verification_Code\">link</a> to activate your account</p>";
```

Comment: the HTML i get in the email doesn't act like a href this is what i get in the email
[ip/ResendVerification.php?passkey=code] as a string not clickable, what are those brackets? and why isn't it 'clickable' with string link as show in my html  ?

Comment: Ok, so the quotes are definetely correct and correctly escaped as shown in my examples?